# Looking seductively at someone

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I am looking for a word or a phrase to describe someone looking seductively at someone. without implying

having considered these:

- [stare](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en-IN&source=hp&q=stare%20meaning&gbv=2&oq=stare%20meaning&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3...174091.181684.0.181856.24.16.6.1.1.0.235.1813.0j10j2.12.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..5.19.1876.PpAUGd0AxZw)
- gaze

But none of these words connote the seductive sense.

Comment: *Seductive* has a wide range of synonyms of varying inflections of nuance, taste and decency. But simply replacing *looking seductively* with, for example, *looking amorously*, presumably does not do the business. You seem to require a single word which replaces *looking seductively*. I can't think of one.

Comment: Have you tried Googling "seductive synonym"?  There's a wealth of options there...http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/seductive

Comment: I am looking for a single word or words which replaces looking seductively.

Comment: I don't think one "looks seductively".  Rather, one may look "longingly", meaning the person looking is being seduced.  Seductiveness (of the other party) only occurs when the other person looks back and observes something.

Comment: Really @HotLicks?  Google image of "Jessica Rabbit" for an example of looking seductively! lol!

Comment: @KristinaLopez - That's a different meaning of the word "looking".  If you are "looking at" something or someone the word does **not** mean "adopting the appearance of".

Comment: If they've reached the point of 'ogling" each other then seduction probably isn't going to be necessary, but "ogling" does mean: "To look or stare at, especially in a desirous manner." https://dictionary.search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0LEVjx6x7ZUHioARgYlnIlQ;_ylu=X3oDMTBsa3ZzMnBvBHNlYwNzYwRjb2xvA2JmMQR2dGlkAw--?p=ogle&.sep=#variation

Comment: @HotLicks, huh?  You have to imagine that Jessica Rabbit is looking at someone with that expression and body language...not just adopting the look of seduction!  Anyway, if it was a case of adopting a look of seduction, it would be "looking seductive", not "looking seductively" as the OP requested. IMO, of course! :-)

Comment: [***Bedroom eyes***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bedroom+eyes).

Comment: Without implying what?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Anne Heche to Harrison Ford](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120828/quotes): Oh, don't give me that, you were ogling.

[1-ogle,](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ogle) 
look at with amorously  (vocabulay.com)

[2-give the glad eye,](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/give%20the%20glad%20eye) 
look seductively at someone (vocabulay.com)

Comment: OMG, I found a verb- give the glad eye, but why is it not 
"give a glad eye".

Comment: With Anne Heche it might be "give the gay eye", depending on when in her career/life you're discussing.

Comment: +1, not for "ogle", though i have watched 6 days and 7 nights..I find "give the glad eye" an excellent to know verb which fits in completely. though, it appears that the answer is still open to debate.

Answer (score 6):

The suggestions ogle and leer both have quite negative connotations, and they're motivated more by expressing desire than the intent to seduce.  Suggestions I have are simply using "seductive gaze", "sultry gaze", or "flirtateous look."

Answer (score 4):

Macmillan states that to [*eye*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/eye_25#eye_31) someone is "to look at someone in a way that shows you are sexually attracted to them."

Note that Macmillan tags this usage as `AMERICAN`; it's likely a shortened form of the more common *[make eyes at someone](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/eye#eye__80)*.

Comment: I would not say that "to eye" is nearly so well-defined in terms of implying sexual interest.  A detective might "eye" the subject of his stakeout, without any sexual motivation at all.

Comment: To 'eye' something is usually to watch something with interest, and when the subject of that interest is a person, I'd make the case that that interest is usually based upon suspicion or sexual interest, depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

You could call it a [*come-hither look*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come-hither).

Answer (score 1):

In Gilbert and Sullivan’s *Ruddigore,* the melodramatic madwoman blames her condition on her having been seduced and abandoned by the melodramatic villain or “bad baronet”; and she describes the former operation as having been effected by means of “an Italian glance.” (The libretto thereupon calls for her to demonstrate, mightily puzzling many a mezzo.) A little less *recherché,* perhaps, but rather specific to a woman’s seducing a man, is the phrase *[to bat one’s eyelashes](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bat_2).*

Answer (score 1):

To [leer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leer) may be used to suggest the idea of a seductive look:

> - to look with a sidelong glance, indicative especially of sexual desire or sly and malicious intent.

- Do not leer at women with low cut tops.

Comment: A leer is an unpleasant facial expression.

Comment: leer: a desirous, sly, or knowing look.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leer

Comment: Leer has very negative connotations: more creepy or pervy than seductive.

Comment: I don't see why seductive is supposted to have a 'positive' connotation. Why shoudn't  a 'dirty' look be seductive?

Comment: Leer implies that the leerer is interested, but also that it's creepy and will have an effect opposite seduction.

Answer (score 1):

Hannibal Lecter to Clarice Starling:

> No. We begin by coveting what we see every day. Don't you feel eyes moving over your body, Clarice? And don't your eyes seek out the things you want?

**Covet** 
1.  cov•et verb \ˈkə-vət\ : to want (something that you do not have) very much (transitive verb): to wish for earnestly  
2.  to desire (what belongs to another) inordinately or culpably

**Covetous**; 
1.  (Adjective) Inordinately desirous; excessively eager to obtain and possess (especially money); avaricious;
— cov•et•able -və-tə-bəl\ *adjective* 
— cov•et•er -tər\ *noun* 
— cov•et•ing•ly -tiŋ-lē\ *adverb*

from Definitions.net

Answer (score 1):

A few of suggestions:

- As Juliet walked in the room, Romeo stole a siren glance.
- As Cathy rode across the moor, Heathcliff gazed lasciviously.
- As Elizabeth bosom heaved, Darcy's quivering lips could not conceal his bedroom eyes.
- As Cleopatra's form unrolled from her carpet, Anthony stared alluringly.
- Noticing Henry's stare, Ann blinked coquettishly.

Answer (score -1):

***[Wink](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wink)*** communicates affection with the eyes and can become a seductive signal:

> VERB
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> 1. Close and open one eye quickly, typically to indicate
>      that something is a joke or a secret or as a signal of affection or
>      greeting:

Answer (score -2):

Longingly gazed into her eyes.

Longingly tends to portray a sense of desire that may not be full filled.

Comment: ...but does "longingly" convey seduction?

Answer (score -2):

I believe either ogling or leering at someone will denote seductive look.

Comment: Oh dear. Somehow I don't think so.

Comment: Dirty old men might leer at every girl who walks by.

Comment: And dirty young ones, too!

Comment: @LittleEva - Quite right. Dirty old men start off as dirty young men, or even dirty little boys. :)